# Overload resolution of operator new regarding nested classes

Tags: c++, new-operator, overload-resolution

If I overload operators `new` and `delete` for a class with a nested class:

```
class A
{
public:
    static void* operator new(size_t);
    static void operator delete(void*);

    class B;
}
```

Will allocations for instances of `A::B` objects and allocations within `A::B` objects use the overloaded `A::new` and `A::delete` or the global defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, chances are very high that you do not need to overload `new` nor `delete` and should avoid doing so.

Baring that, the overloaded operators are going to apply to class `A`, not to class `A::B`.  If you wanted to have B with overloaded operators, you would need to overload them in class `B` as well.

For an example of how to overload `new` and `delete`:  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html

Answer (score 1):

No.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){printf("A\n");}
    ~A(){}
    static void* operator new(size_t t){
        printf("A new\n");
        ::operator new(t);
    }
    static void operator delete(void* t){
        printf("A delete\n");
        ::operator delete(t);
    }

    void check_B(){
        b = new B();
        ::operator delete(b);
    }

    class B{
    public:
        B(){}
    };

    B* b;
};

class C : public A {

};
```

test:

```
int main(void)
{
    A* a = new A;
    printf("\ncheck ------\n");
    a->check_B();
    printf("\ncheck ------\n");
    delete a;

    C* c = new C;
    A* cc = new C;

    delete c;
    delete cc;
return 0;
}
```

> output:
>
> A
>
> new A
>
> check ------
>
> check ------
>
> A delete
>
> A new
>
> A
>
> A new
>
> A
>
> A delete
>
> A delete
>
> RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 64ms)

valgrind:

```
==9318== 
==9318== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9318==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9318==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 25 bytes allocated
==9318== 
==9318== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9318== 
==9318== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9318== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

---

It won't be even called for `new A[]` unless you overload `operator new[]()` as well. You need to overload them for nested class `A::B` accordingly. However as we see they will be called for classes derived from A.

Test, test, test. Do the test is always better than not do the test. Author: me.